# Problem pip installing elasticsearch client for python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pip

I have a server that is not connected to the Internet that I want to install the Elasticsearch python client. The server is on RHEL 7.9, with Python 3.6.8 (running `python` is version 2.7.5, while running `python3` is version 3.6.8).

Apparently, the `elasticsearch-8.4.0` package requires `elastic_transport-8.4.0`. When I tried to install `elastic_transport-8.4.0`, I get the following error message.

```
[localhost]# python3 -m pip install elastic_transport-8.4.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting dataclasses; python_version < "3.7" (from elastic-transport==8.4.0)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dataclasses; python_version < "3.7" (from elastic-transport==8.4.0) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dataclasses; python_version < "3.7" (from elastic-transport==8.4.0)
```

I don't understand why I'm seeing this error message, because I do have python version 3.6.8.